# AjaxMethod "Class" is undefined error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an old project asp.net that uses Ajax.AjaxMethod() to call server side code from Javascript. It was working fine before (and by before I meant years ago) but now it has stopped working.

This is my C# code behind:

```
public partial class Signup : System.Web.UI.Page{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(Signup));
    }

    [Ajax.AjaxMethod()]
    public DataTable fillStateDdl(int countryid)
    {
      objState = new MyClass.State();
      DataTable dtState = new DataTable();
      objState.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(countryid);
      dtState = objState.GetStateCountry().Tables[0];
      return dtState;
    }
}
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
function fillStates(countryid)
{
  var cntryid=countryid.options[countryid.selectedIndex].value;
  var response=Signup.fillStateDdl(cntryid);

  var states=response.value;
}
```

In javascript I am getting "Microsoft JScript error: 'Signup' is undefined" error message. Am I missing something here?

Comment: yes there is a reference file of Ajax.dll

Answer (score 1):

You better seperate your AjaxMethod.

```
public partial class Signup : System.Web.UI.Page{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(YourAjaxClass));
    }
}

public class YourAjaxClass {

    [Ajax.AjaxMethod()]
    public DataTable fillStateDdl(int countryid)
    {
      objState = new MyClass.State();
      DataTable dtState = new DataTable();
      objState.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(countryid);
      dtState = objState.GetStateCountry().Tables[0];
      return dtState;
    }
}
```

You cannot RegisterTypeForAjax object which is inherits from System.Web.Ui.Page.
It won't work.

Then you can call it from javascript.

```
function fillStates(countryid)
{
  var cntryid=countryid.options[countryid.selectedIndex].value;
  var response=YourAjaxClass.fillStateDdl(cntryid);

  var states=response.value;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of separate class... but can't test it on the mentioned project anymore :(

Comment: Joshua, turns out you can do that ( RegisterTypeForAjax, and use a class that inherits from System.Web.Ui.Page ). However, in our case, we have not figured out how it works. We have legacy production code doing this. The problem for us is that it is working in production, but not on the systems we are tying to test with (debug, fix issues, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing http handler for the ajax. Add these in web.config under system.web

```
<system.web>
<-- 

Other configuration


 -->

<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET" path="*.ashx" type="Ajax.AjaxHandlerFactory,Ajax"/>
</httpHandlers>

</system.web>
```

Comment: This is what I had earlier:
<add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax"/>

then I change the path to look like yours but it didn't work :( I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Class Signup should be public

Comment: public partial class Signup : System.Web.UI.Page

this is the actual class definition.. I am going to update my question with this change also

Comment: Reset IIS, that may bring some luck.

Comment: I doubt that :( but how u do that?

Comment: In Run window type inetmgr command to open IIS, right click its instance and restart it

Comment: https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a191/how-to-reset-iis-with-the-iis-reset-command.aspx  You can search for your specific platform

Comment: Don't know bro :( finally started to use UpdatePanel... thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: What is version of ajax.dll and what version of .net framework you have as I have seen problem with framework 4.0

Comment: it looks like I'm using Ajax 5.7.22.2 and for .Net framework I am using 3.5